# Lumia Imaging SDK JpegRenderer.RenderAsync InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, lumia-imaging-sdk

I'm using Lumia Imaging SDK ver 2.0 to crop images in Windows Phone 8.1 RT application. The code works fine, but `JpegRenderer.RenderAsync()` sometimes throws `InvalidOperationException, Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.`

The issue reproduces every time with a some images, and crashes the application. I use the following code for cropping:

```
using (StorageFileImageSource inputImageSource = new StorageFileImageSource(inputImageFile))
{
    using (FilterEffect filterEffect = new FilterEffect(inputImageSource))
    {
        // Create cropping filter.
        List<IFilter> filters = new List<IFilter>();
        CropFilter cropFilter = new CropFilter(croppedImageSize);
        filters.Add(cropFilter);

        // Add filters to effects.
        filterEffect.Filters = filters;

        // Create renderer with above filters and render new image.
        using (JpegRenderer renderer = new JpegRenderer(filterEffect))
        {
                IBuffer croppedImage = await renderer.RenderAsync();
                return croppedImage.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I referred to [this resource](http://157.56.25.106/en-us/library/dn859585.aspx) and it says the `JpegRenderer.RenderAsync()` throws `InvalidOperationException` when the filter property value changes while the rendering is in progress. I don't change the value of the property once it's set, then why is the exception being thrown?

Comment: What is the size you are passing into the CropFilter(croppedImageSize)? The crop takes the size in absolute coordinates and the size must not be larger than the image, otherwise an exception will be thrown. I can't say more without more details, but it could explain why it "happens for some images."

Comment: Yes, thanks. I figured it out. I was passing the wrong dimensions, because I was getting incorrect values from `BitmapDecoder` for images which had EXIF data.

Comment: @DavidBožjak, I removed `BitmapDecoder` and used `ImageProperties` to calculate height and width of the image. But it gave me a new problem: `ImageProperties` works for an image only if the extension is preserved. I store images after removing their extensions. Consequently, the height/width of images stored in my app is 0. How can I workaround this? I don't really want to use `BitmapDecoder`; have to open a complete stream for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem, and as [David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751771/lumia-imaging-sdk-jpegrenderer-renderasync-invalidoperationexception?noredirect=1#comment55283296_33751771) said, I was passing wrong dimensions which were larger than the size of the image. I was using `BitmapDecoder.PixelHeight` and `BitmapDecoder.PixelWidth` to calculate dimensions.

However, in some images having orientation data in EXIF data, `BitmapDecoder.PixelHeight` gave the width of the image and vice-versa. For this, I had to use `BitmapDecoder.OrientedPixelHeight` and `BitmapDecoder.OrientedPixelWidth` to get the actual height and width of the image, accommodating the orientation of the image.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. This is totally valid, but I did just want to point out that the Lumia Imaging SDK does have a way to report the image size: GetInfoAsync(): It returns a ImageProviderInfo object that contains a ImageSize property. So if you *wanted to* you could get the dimensions from the lumia imaging sdk and not juggle two different API's.

Comment: @DavidBožjak just got a prompt the `ImageProviderInfo.ImageSize` is deprecated. Is there any newer method to calculate image sizes?

Comment: It's deprecated in Lumia Imaging SDK 3.0. If I remember correctly (It's been a long while since I've seen Lumia imaging sdk 2.0 code) this is the correct way to get the image size in SDK2.0 code.

Comment: If you have switched to Lumia Imaging SDK3.0 (your question refers to SDK2.0) then the correct way is by using the IImageResource interface. Take a look at the docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598508.aspx) how to do that depending on your source (How to migrate: Image providers)